# AUP controls enforce

Tags: paypal

Im developing a web app with paypalintegración, they request this:

Can you please enhance the AUP control and provide detailed information about those controls.

Can someone explain ehat this mean?

I would like someone has implemented that Kinded of validation and can share it with me

Comment: AUP is acceptable use policy, beyond that impossible to say